# Assign variable to values in array php

Tags: php, variables, split

This is what I want to do:

1. Split a word into separate charachters. The input word comes from a form and can differ from each user.
2. Assign variables to each charachter so that i can manipulate them separately.

Her's my code so far (which doesn't work). Apoligize if ther's a lot of stupid mistakes here, but I am new to PHP.

```
<?php

$word = $_POST['input'];

//split word into charachters

$arr1 = str_split($word);

//assigning a variable to each charchter 

$bokstaver = array();

while($row = $arr1)
{
$bokstaver[] = $row[];
}

$int_count = count($bokstaver);
$i=0;

foreach ($bokstaver as $tecken) {
$var = 'tecken' . ($i + 1);
$$var = $tecken;
$i++;
} 

?>
```

I'd like to end up with as many $tecken variables (With the names $tecken, t$tecken1, $tecken2 etc) as the number of charachters in the input.

All help much appreciated, as always!

Comment: Dynamically creating variable names is asking for trouble.  I'd strongly suggest using an array.

Comment: Is there any special reason why you can't simply use the array created by str_split()?

Comment: Its says: Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in C:\xampp\htdocs\Quiz\hangmanindex.php on line 15

Comment: Thank you msgmash.com for your asnwer, but could you be more specific. This is for a word game application that I was hoping to build. I just figured PHP would be a suitable language, but as i said, I'm quite new to php som maybe php isn't a good choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create separate variables for each letter because you have all the letters in an array. Then you just index into the array to get out each letter.

Here is how I would do it.

```
//get the word from the form
$word = $_POST['input'];

//split word into characters 
$characters = str_split($word);


//suppose the word is "jim"
//this prints out 
// j
// i
// m

foreach($characters as $char)
    print $char . "\n"


//now suppose you want to change the first letter so the word now reads "tim"
//Access the first element in the array (ie, the first letter) using this syntax
$characters[0] = "t";
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its a good idea, but heres how you do it:

```
<?php
$input = 'Hello world!';
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++) {
    ${'character' . $i} = $input[$i];
}
```

Comment: This is what the OP asks for, but it's always a bad idea to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jon! But why is this a bad idea, and what would be a better way to do it then.

Comment: @user1009453 It depends on what you *actually* want to do. If you need a set of characters, any string is already it. (As you can see by this example)

Comment: This is for a simple word game application that I was hoping to build.  The idea is that player1 chooses a word, and player2 tries to guess the word by guessing one charachter at a time (he can se how many letters the word consits of) If player2 to gets a match then the letter in the word is made visible to him. I just figured I had to split the original word into separate vars so that these could be treated individually. maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @user1009453 You can access the characters of a string individually by index: `echo $input[2]` will output the third character

Comment: @user1009453 For your purposes, the array returned by `str_split()` will do exactly what you want. An array is a collection of separate values that can be individually manipulated in a much cleaner way than using variable variables. For character `0`, just use `$array[0]` instead of `$string0` and it will do exactly the same thing. But as people have pointed out, you don't even need to split the string if you want to access characters one at a time, you can just do `$string[0]` to get the first character.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the kind and informative help. I will look at all the examples you have provided and hopefully learn a whole lot more. I think I can solve this with the guidelines that you have provided, if not I will try to post a new perhaps more specific question. Once again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

why do you want that?
you can just go with:

```
$word = 'test';
echo $word[2]; // returns 's'
echo $word{2}; // returns 's'
$word{2} = 'b';
echo $word{2}; //returns 'b'
echo $word; // returns 'tebt'
...
```

Comment: It is worth noting that `$var[0]` is the "correct" way to do this. `$var{0}` syntax *was* unofficially deprecated for strings in PHP6, although reading through the manual it looks as this is no longer the case since it was merged with the 5.3 trunk.

Comment: str_split() still here and syntax would be same